# Transfer ether in solidity 0.5.16 with truffle

Tags: solidity, truffle, ether, ganache, solidity-0.5.x

I am currently working with Truffle and Ganache, therefore I use Solidity compiler version 0.5.16. With that version I have some problems to send ethers. I want to transfer ether to a specific address.
In my smart contract I have a function:

```
function newToken(address generator, address payable receiver) payable public returns(bool success) 
{
    receiver.transfer(1 ether);
    //some other logic
}
```

In addition I have the following fallback function:

```
function() external payable 
{
}
```

I am not able to transfer ether with this code, it always throws a bunch of errors. How should I call this transfer process and is it correct?

Comment: Does the contract have enough ether to send it? `recipient.transfer(amount)` will transfer `amount` ethers from the contract's balance to `recipient`. The contract has to have enough balance.

Comment: For my understanding yes, because I send a transaction with a value of 1 ether.

Comment: How are you calling this function from Truffle?

Comment: @currImid Is the receiver a contract? Does it have a fallback or a receive function?